# Install Tensorflow cpu without internet acess

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to install Tensorflow on a machine (Windows 10 Pro) that doesn't have access to the Internet. My strategy was to install Tensorflow using a .whl file (tensorflow-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64) to try to import it and see what errors could occur.
With this strategy, I could see that the following libs were missing:

- astro-0.8.1
- gast-0.3.3
- google-2.0.3
- numpy-1.18.2
- opt_einsum-3.2.0
- protobuf-3.11.3
- PyYAML-5.3.1
- six-1.14.0

I also installed Microsoft Visual C ++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 required by Tensorflow.

With that it was possible to import Tensorflow, obtaining the following warnings:

```
2020-03-22 12:08:36.681758: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-03-22 12:08:36.693101: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
```

These warnings are ok, because I don't have a GPU and I don't need the TensorBoard. But I am also getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Ocr_flex\Desktop\Imagem_Teste.py", line 275, in <module>
        modelo_cnn = keras.models.load_model(os.path.join(PATH_MODELS, f"CNN_{models}.h5"))
      File "C:\Users\Ocr_flex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
        module = self._load()
      File "C:\Users\Ocr_flex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
        module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
      File "C:\Users\Ocr_flex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras'
```

I don't know what packages to install anymore. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of research ([Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386)), I realized that the CPU on which I was building Tensorflow did not support AVX ([Here](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/47924/intel-xeon-processor-e5630-12m-cache-2-53-ghz-5-86-gt-s-intel-qpi.html)), so I need to build it from the source.

Thanks to everyone who tried to answer this question.